# Non existence (or existence) of a set that is equidistributed modulo $q$ for every $q$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

I have been thinking about some set that is equidistributed modulo $q$,
uniformly in $q$ in some sense. I was starting to think this particular condition, which I describe below, is too strong and that I am starting to doubt if any such set even exists.

However, I haven't been able to prove no such set exists. I was wondering if someone
could tell me how to prove that such set does not exist (or that does exist). I would
also appreciate any input or discussion on whether such set exists or not. It would be great if I could get a better understanding! Thank you very much!

Let $\gamma >\theta >0$, and some $\epsilon >0$ small.  Let $B \subseteq  \mathbb{N}$ and $B \cap [1,X] \sim X^{\gamma}$. Suppose given any 
$q \in \mathbb{N}$ and any partition of the residue class
modulo $q$, $\{ J_l \}_{l=1}^L$, such that $|J_l|X^{\gamma}/q > X^{\epsilon}$,
we have
$$
\sum_{l=1}^L| \  \# \{ u \in B : u \leq X, u \equiv J_l (\text{mod }q) \} - (|J_l|X^{\gamma})/q \ |
\ll X^{\gamma - \theta}.
$$ 
I am wondering does such a set $B$ exist?
If $J = \{ r_1, .., r_k \}$, by
$u \equiv J (\text{mod }q)$, I mean $u \equiv r_j (\text{mod }q)$
for some $j \in \{1, ..., k \}$. Thanks!

Comment: When is something "very well distributed"? I have never heard the term before.

Comment: oops. let me fix that.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/163407/is-every-sufficiently-dense-well-mixed-set-an-additive-basis. I think my answer gives an example

Comment: Do you have access to the Kuipers-Niederreiter book, SJY? That's the first place I'd look.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thank you for your comment! Does the "Ergodic Theorem" you are using in your solution, give a bound on the error by any chance? I can't quite see how this is an example yet. It would be nice if it is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! Is it the "Uniform distribution of sequences"? I will go to the library first thing tomorrow morning!

Comment: Yes, that's the book.